# Transform a day of the year to day_month format

Tags: apache-spark, date, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

So I was wondering if it's possible with PySpark to transform a random day of the year (`0-365`) to `day-month` format. In my case, the input would be a string.

Example:

Input : `"091"`

Expected output (month-day): `"0331"`

Answer (score 0):

This is possible but you need to have to year also. Convert the year to date (first January of that year) and add the days to get the desired result, then format it.

Here's a working example

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


df = spark.createDataFrame([("2020", "091")], ["year", "day_of_year"])

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "first_day_year",
    F.concat_ws("-", "year", F.lit("01"), F.lit("01"))
).withColumn(
    "day_month",
    F.date_format(
        F.expr("date_add(first_day_year, cast(day_of_year as int) -1)"),
        "MMdd"
    )
).drop("first_day_year")

df1.show()

#+----+-----------+---------+
#|year|day_of_year|day_month|
#+----+-----------+---------+
#|2020|        091|     0331|
#+----+-----------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_add` to add the number of days to the new year's day.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'day_month',
    F.expr("date_format(date_add('2020-01-01', int(day - 1)), 'MMdd')")
)

df2.show()
+---+---------+
|day|day_month|
+---+---------+
| 91|     0331|
+---+---------+
```

Note that the result will vary depending on whether it's a leap year or not.